# onAdClosed() not getting called within app

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to understand why onAdClosed() doesn't get called after a user closes an ad?

I'll trying to create a new InterstitialAd to load and display later using the display method.

Any advice would be great, thanks guys.

### Code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);
    createAdmobBanner();

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxx");

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequestIN = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequestIN);



 // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an     interstitial.
public void displayInterstitial() 
{
  if (interstitial.isLoaded()) 
  {
    interstitial.show();
    Log.d("response", "AD IS LOADED: ");
  }

  else 
  {
        Log.d("response", "AD IS NOT LOADED: "  );
  }
}



  public void onAdClosed() 
  {
         // Create the interstitial.
         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
       interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxx");

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequestIN = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequestIN);

     Log.d("response", "onAdClosed: "  );


}
```

Comment: I think you should clarify what do you mean by "close an Ad". Do you mean the user clicks on the 'X' to dismiss the Ad, or rather you mean that the user clicked on the Ad and later they closed it?

Comment: When a user closes an ad. When they click the 'X' to close the ad.

Answer (score 2):

It required an AdListener.

```
// Set an AdListener.
     mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded() {
             Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                     "The interstitial is loaded",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdClosed() {
             // Proceed to the next level.
             goToNextLevel();
         }
     });
```

**Useless link for beginners:(Not Working)**
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd

Answer (score 0):

There's a misunderstanding on what you understand as closing and what `Android` defines as closing an Ad. What you mean is called dismissing the ad, while for Android, closing the Ad, as referenced by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#onAdClosed%28%29) is:

> Called when the user is about to return to the application **after
>   clicking on an ad**.

You can find more info [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#onAdClosed%28%29).

Comment: Is there any way then to detect when de Ad is being dismissed?

Comment: Didn't find a way myself.

Answer (score 0):

In this version in your gradle.file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
```

in your Activity.java just load Interstitial Ad in onCreate function

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadInterstitialAd();
        ...
}
```

after implementation your loadInterstitialAd(); method paste this code when you show your ads

```
public void displayInterstitial() 
{
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                mInterstitialAd.show(this);
                mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                        startActivity();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                startActivity();
            }
}
```